# sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I've never dealt with file uploading before this is my first time and I followed the instructions on youtube. Apparently when I added a FileField in my models and tried to migrate, it threw me some exceptions and I don't know how to fix it. I tried to remove the parameters but it still gave me an error. Pls help me (Im using django btw)

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    profile_photo = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

and then this error came up which I cant understand

```
Running migrations:
  Applying bartr.0011_profile_profile_photo...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: bartr_profile.profile_photo
```

Comment: execute `.schema TABLENAME` where TABLENAME is you table name in sqllite and check if the profile_photo column constraint is set to NOT NULL by default.

Comment: @Keerthana Hello, I'm sorry I didnt quite get what you meant. What I do understand as of now is I forced my profile_photo to accept nulls. Right now I'm having a problem when Im trying to put a value in it and it gives me the integrity error. Could you explain more? I also dont know where to execute that Im using pycharm